# How to place something in a triangle-shaped box?

Tags: css, html

I found various examples of how to create triangles using CSS (like [this one](http://html-generator.weebly.com/css-triangle-generator.html)); all of them are based on creating a 0-sized box and fiddling with borders to create the triangle shape. Ok, very nice.

But how can I actually place something inside such a triangle?

Comment: same as you place anything in a div or element.

Comment: @otherDewi, this would not work: the box has an effective size of 0, and enlarging it would disrupt the triangle shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *positioning* techniques to place some content *over* the triangle and not *under* the triangle..

I emphasized over and under because using positioning am positioning the text over the triangle, so triangle element isn't the parent of the content, as to create triangles we use `height: 0;` and `width: 0;` so you need to overlay the text.

Just make sure you use `position: relative;` for parent element holding `absolute` positioned element.

Didn't used `z-index` but you can use that to play safe with the stacking order.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h7f5w/)

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
    <span>Hello</span>
</div>

div.wrap {
    position: relative;
}

div.triangle {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border: 50px solid #f00;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
}

div span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 35px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thought it has to be something like this. Works great, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This way can be sloppy but it would work for a basic situation.

http://jsfiddle.net/Yc5nF/1/

```
<div class="arrow-right">
    <p>Foobar</p>
</div>

.arrow-right {
  position: relative;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;  
  border-bottom: 150px solid green;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
 }
 .arrow-right p {
   position: absolute;
   top: 70px;
   left: -20px;
 }
```